# bash: How to prepend a string to stderr lines and combine both stdout and stderr in exact order and store in one variable in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, stderr, io-redirection, prepend

What I have done so far is :

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')

var=$(
        sleep 1 ; 
        hostname ; 
        ifconfig | wc -l ; 
        ls /sfsd; 
        ls hasdh;
        mkdir /tmp/asdasasd/asdasd/asdasd;
        ls /tmp ;
) 

echo "$var"
```

This does prepend ERROR= at the start of each error lines, but displays all errors first and then stdout, (not in order in which it was executed).

If we skip storing the output in variable and execute the commands directly, the output comes in desired order.

Any expert opinion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The primary problem with your script is that the command substitution `$(...)` only captures the subshell's standard output; the subshell's standard error still just flows through to the parent shell's standard error. As it happens, you've redirected the parent shell's standard error in a way that ends up populating the parent shell's standard output; but that completely circumvents the `$(...)`, which is only capturing the *subshell's* standard output.

Do you see what I mean?

So, you can fix that by redirecting the *subshell's* standard error in a way that ends up populating *its* standard output, which is what gets captured:

```
var=$(
    exec 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    sleep 1
    hostname
    ifconfig | wc -l
    ls /sfsd
    ls hasdh
    mkdir /tmp/asdasasd/asdasd/asdasd
    ls /tmp
)

echo "$var"
```

Even so, this does not *guarantee* proper ordering of lines. The problem is that `sed` is running in parallel with everything else in the subshell, so while it's just received an error-line and is busy planning to write to standard output, one of the later commands in the subshell can be plowing ahead and already writing more things to standard output!

You can improve that by launching `sed` separately for each command, so that the shell will wait for `sed` to complete before proceeding to the next command:

```
var=$(
    sleep 1 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    hostname 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    { ifconfig | wc -l ; } 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    ls /sfsd 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    ls hasdh 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    mkdir /tmp/asdasasd/asdasd/asdasd 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    ls /tmp 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
)

echo "$var"
```

Even so, `sed` will be running concurrently with each command, so if any of those commands is a complicated command that writes both to standard output and to standard error, then the order that that command's output is captured in may not match the order in which the command actually wrote it. But this should probably be good enough for your purposes.

You can improve the readability a bit by creating a wrapper function for the simple-command (non-pipeline) case:

```
var=$(
    function fix-stderr () {
       "$@" 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR= /')
    }

    fix-stderr sleep 1
    fix-stderr hostname
    fix-stderr eval 'ifconfig | wc -l'   # using eval to get a simple command
    fix-stderr ls /sfsd
    fix-stderr ls hasdh
    fix-stderr mkdir /tmp/asdasasd/asdasd/asdasd
    fix-stderr ls /tmp
)

echo "$var"
```

Comment: Your answer explains lots of things that were happening unexpectedly, thank you.

Comment: One problem with adding `2> >(sed 's/^/::ERROR:: /')` on each line is, if we want to execute another script file we would execute `./test.sh 2> >(sed 's/^/::ERROR:: /')`, which still gives random ordered output.

Comment: @avg598: Yes, that's right. The whole Unix concept of "streams" is extremely powerful, but it doesn't offer any sort of concept of preserving chronological order between separate streams. You'd have to change your `./test.sh` to support the same sort of functionality.

Answer (score 5):

The `sed` command runs asynchronously from the rest of the shell; its output goes to standard error as soon as it processes its input from the commands in the command substitution. The standard output of those commands, however, are captured in `$var` and not displayed until the `echo` command runs.

Even if you weren't capturing the output, there is a *chance* the standard error and standard output of those commands wouldn't appear as you expect, because the `sed` command that ultimately produces the error messages might not be scheduled by the OS when you expect it to be, delaying the appearance of the error messages.

When you run a command in the usual way from the terminal, that command's standard error and standard output point to the same file: the terminal itself. As such, writes to the file maintain the order in which they occur in the program. As soon as you pipe one or the other to another process, you lose all control over how the two are spliced back together, if ever. In your case, you are redirecting standard error to `sed`, which writes modified lines back to standard output. But you have no control over when the the OS schedules `sed` to run and when your shell runs, so you can't control the order in which lines are written.

It helps to redirect standard error separately for each command:

```
tag_error () { sed 's/^/ERROR= /'; }

hostname 2> >(tag_error)
{ ifconfig | wc -l ; } 2> >(tag_error)
# etc
```

but this still doesn't guarantee that writes from within the same program are ordered as if they were all writing to the same file.

([ruakh has covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38947717/1126841) how to combine this with capturing standard output, so I won't bother adding it now. See his answer.)

Comment: You can't; there are no markers to indicate which lines coming from `sed` and which lines in `$var` correspond to each individual command in the command substitution. The relative output is only merged in the "regular" case because each process's stdout and stderr is the exact same file handle.

Comment: The whole prepending thing I wanted to do was to mark the lines to identify which are from stdout and which are from stderr and at the same time maintaining the order.
Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be putting the commands in an array then execute them within a loop:

```
declare -a cmds=('sleep 1' 'hostname' 'eval ifconfig | wc -l' 'ls /sfsd' 'ls /tmp' 'ls hasdh')

for i in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    $i 2> >(sed -E 's/^/ERROR=/')
done
```

When an error occurs it should print in the same order that it occurred in the execution. Using a command such as `sh script.sh` within the array should also reveal any `stdout` or `stderr` from the resulting external script. For piped command an `eval` will likely be needed as well.

Comment: But it won't work if one of the command is to run a script file which gives both stderr and stdout.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow... If you had a command such as `sh myscript.sh` within the array it would still output both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: Ok, let me verify, meanwhile check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947524/bash-how-to-store-output-of-set-of-commands-in-3-variables-out-err-combined). Main purpose of doing this is in that link.

Comment: I would recommend deleting that question and editing your question here with any additional concerns.

Comment: The idea of redirection standard error separately for each command is a good idea; storing the commands in an array is not.

Comment: @l'L'l 1, I think this question limits the solution to that question. There might be other ways to do that. This is why I asked the two separate questions.

Comment: @chepner, What other suggestion would you have, and why not store the commands in an array?

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for details.

Comment: @l'L'l 1, can you please remove -ve vote on the other question, since these two questions are different?

Comment: @avg598: What makes you think I downvoted it? If you do you're incorrect.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for the link, and what it talks about makes sense. So I'm guessing by what it says that parsing the command from a .txt file would be better, although I'm not sure how that would be a whole lot different actually if an array of commands was constructed properly. I'm sort of in a hurry though, so can't add additional info to my answer atm; feel free to edit it if you want, cheers! :)

Comment: @l'L'l 1, I checked by executing `./test.sh 2> >(sed -E 's/^/ERROR=/')`, and it prints the error lines at the end after all stdouts. So, doesn't work.